# iOS - Method With Success And Error Callbacks Without Initial Parameter

Tags: objective-c

I use success and error callback blocks a lot in method definitions with initial parameters like so:

```
+(void)doSomethingWithObject:(MyObject*)myObject successCallback:(void (^)(NSArray*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))error;
```

where `myObject` is the initial parameter. However, I have come across a situation right now where I don't need any parameters. I'm trying to define my method like so:

```
+(void)getSomeData successCallback:(void (^)(NSArray*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))error;
```

But now Xcode is giving me some syntax complaints. How can I define a method without any initial parameters but also having a success and error callback? Is this impossible or is there just something I don't understand about the correct syntax?

Comment: `success` is the initial parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit to

```
+(void)getSomeDataSuccessCallback:(void (^)(NSArray*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))error;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked exactly how my other methods did. I didn't know the change was that simple. I thought it would behave differently if I did it that way.